# RAID configuration of a Sun Blade X6270 M2 Server Module

Tags: raid, sun, blade-server

One **Sun Blade X6270 M2 server module** has four **146GB disks**, but the running RHEL5-x64 O.S. finds only a 146GB disk. I guess two from the four disks are a RAID 1 volume -- the one found by O.S; and the two remaining disks are unused.

I need a tool to (at least) **display the current RAID configuration and configure the other two disks to create a new RAID volumen and make it available to the O.S**.

Do you know any tool to achieve this?

I tried to use the ILOM-CMM but I find no disk drive information.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

**sas2ircu** is an [Avago Technology](http://www.avagotech.com/) tool to get that information. No instalation is required -- the tool is a single binary ([click here to browse its download page](http://www.avagotech.com/support/oem/oracle/6Gb/sg_x_sas6-rem-z)).

```
# ./sas2ircu
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 11.00.00.03 (2011.10.14) Copyright (c) 2009-2011
LSI Corporation. All rights reserved.

SAS2IRCU: No command specified.
  sas2ircu <controller #> <command> <parameters> ...
    where <controller #> is:
      Number between 0 and 255
    where <command> is:
      DISPLAY    - display controller, volume and physical device info
      LIST       - Lists all available LSI adapters (does not need ctlr #>
      CREATE     - create an IR volume
      DELETE     - Delete entire RAID configuration on the selected controller
      DELETEVOLUME  - Delete a specific RAID Volume on the selected controller
      HOTSPARE   - make drive a hot spare
      STATUS     - display current volume status info
      CONSTCHK   - Start Consistency Check operation on the specified IR Volume
      ACTIVATE   - Activate an Inactive IR volume
      LOCATE     - Locate a disk drive on an enclosure
      LOGIR      - Upload or Clear IR Log data
      BOOTIR     - Select an IR Boot Volume as primary boot device
      BOOTENCL   - Select an Enclosure/Bay as primary boot device
      HELP       - Display help information
    where <parameters> are:
      Command specific values; enter "sas2ircu <controller #> <command>"
      to get command specific help
```

**sas2ircu** commands need a controller number (or index). That controller number is given by the **list** command:

```
# ./sas2ircu list
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 11.00.00.03 (2011.10.14) 
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved. 


         Adapter      Vendor  Device                       SubSys  SubSys 
 Index    Type          ID      ID    Pci Address          Ven ID  Dev ID 
 -----  ------------  ------  ------  -----------------    ------  ------ 
   0       SAS2008     1000h    72h   00h:01h:00h:00h      1000h   3180h
```

One you know the controller ID, you can use the **status** command to get information about the RAID volume:

```
# ./sas2ircu 0 status
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 11.00.00.03 (2011.10.14) 
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Background command progress status for controller 0...
IR Volume 1
  Volume ID                               : 902
  Current operation                       : None
  Volume status                           : Enabled
  Volume state                            : Optimal
  Volume wwid                             : 0c73f86fdc7305cf
  Physical disk I/Os                      : Not quiesced
SAS2IRCU: Command STATUS Completed Successfully.
SAS2IRCU: Utility Completed Successfully.
```

Or use the **display** command to get all details:

```
# ./sas2ircu 0 display
LSI Corporation SAS2 IR Configuration Utility.
Version 11.00.00.03 (2011.10.14) 
Copyright (c) 2009-2011 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Read configuration has been initiated for controller 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Controller type                         : SAS2008
  BIOS version                            : 7.03.04.00
  Firmware version                        : 4.05.52.00
  Channel description                     : 1 Serial Attached SCSI
  Initiator ID                            : 0
  Maximum physical devices                : 831
  Concurrent commands supported           : 1775
  Slot                                    : 0
  Segment                                 : 0
  Bus                                     : 1
  Device                                  : 0
  Function                                : 0
  RAID Support                            : Yes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR Volume information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IR volume 1
  Volume ID                               : 902
  Status of volume                        : Okay (OKY)
  Volume wwid                             : 0c73f86fdc7305cf
  RAID level                              : RAID1
  Size (in MB)                            : 139236
  Physical hard disks                     :
  PHY[0] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 1:0
  PHY[1] Enclosure#/Slot#                 : 1:1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical device information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initiator at ID #0

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 0
  SAS Address                             : 5000cca-0-0ad9-9d21
  State                                   : Optimal (OPT)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 140009/286739328
  Manufacturer                            : HITACHI 
  Model Number                            : H103014SCSUN146G
  Firmware Revision                       : A2A8
  Serial No                               : 001039FVP2DE
  GUID                                    : 5000cca00ad99d20
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 1
  SAS Address                             : 5000cca-0-0ad9-6fd5
  State                                   : Optimal (OPT)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 140009/286739328
  Manufacturer                            : HITACHI 
  Model Number                            : H103014SCSUN146G
  Firmware Revision                       : A2A8
  Serial No                               : 001039FVL1WE
  GUID                                    : 5000cca00ad96fd4
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 2
  SAS Address                             : 5000cca-0-0ad7-ed1d
  State                                   : Hot Spare (HSP)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 140009/286739328
  Manufacturer                            : HITACHI 
  Model Number                            : H103014SCSUN146G
  Firmware Revision                       : A2A8
  Serial No                               : 001039FUS9HE
  GUID                                    : 5000cca00ad7ed1c
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD

Device is a Hard disk
  Enclosure #                             : 1
  Slot #                                  : 3
  SAS Address                             : 5000cca-0-0ad8-59d9
  State                                   : Hot Spare (HSP)
  Size (in MB)/(in sectors)               : 140009/286739328
  Manufacturer                            : HITACHI 
  Model Number                            : H103014SCSUN146G
  Firmware Revision                       : A2A8
  Serial No                               : 001039FUZJZE
  GUID                                    : 5000cca00ad859d8
  Protocol                                : SAS
  Drive Type                              : SAS_HDD
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enclosure information
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Enclosure#                              : 1
  Logical ID                              : 500605b0:028cd7c0
  Numslots                                : 8
  StartSlot                               : 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SAS2IRCU: Command DISPLAY Completed Successfully.
SAS2IRCU: Utility Completed Successfully.
```

Here you can see the RAID configuration of the internal SAS disks: 2 disks for the RAID-1 volume and the 2 **hot spare** disks.

---

Thanks to [Pascal Kreyer answer](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3881154) for his help.

Comment: And for complete access, look for a copy of `lsiutil` - but if you go that route, be careful. `lsiutil` can brick your hardware.

Comment: @Andrew, unlike **`sas2ircu`**, **`lsiutil`** does not provide information about the RAID configuration -- it merely displays the RAID disks. Thanks for your help, anyway :)

Comment: *`lsiutil` does not provide information about the RAID configuration -- it merely displays the RAID disks. Thanks for your help, anyway* Per the user guide: [Option 21 RAID Actions, suboption 1 Show Volumes](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wikiDE/images/4/44/Lsi_userguide_2006_20130528.pdf)  Here's an [example](http://www.unixarena.com/2015/05/how-to-rebuild-hardware-raid-from-os-level.html).  Do you have anything else to add?

Comment: @Andrew, just apologies and a request -- you appear to master the **``lsiutil``** tool. Why does you not add an answer in order to be properly rewarded?

Comment: I have no problem to admit my first comment was a mistake and I would want your help to be recognized as useful as Pascal Kreyer's is. I think your contribution is worthy to appear like an answer, not just like a simple comment.